# Mvc2 areas and session

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, session, areas

Do Areas in Mvc2 have session isolation or do they share the same session as the rest of the application for the same user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are part of the same ASP.NET application and therefore they share the same session.

Comment: Well I dont seem to find that true as my request for the same session set in different area of mvc comes as null, where as in that area it works fine

Comment: Can you elaborate in your question please. Give us some code and some knowledge about how the application is setup in visual studio and IIS. Ta.

Answer (score 0):

> Well I dont seem to find that true as my request for the same session set in different area of mvc comes as null, where as in that area it works fine

But they do, just like @Charlino said, it uses ASP.NET's session. Maybe you don't have just areas, but have actually separate virtual directories/applications.

Are you using Session[], or TempData[]. I don't think it makes a difference, but TempData is a MVC mechanism so might have an extra hook in there.

Comment: Well its simple I have a  session in an area where i do this          Session[SessionName]=something works fine but in  main app i set this session variable to null by saying the samething but = null, and here on the application crashes with debugger showing null=null, even at the watch it shows null.

Comment: 1. careful if in the watch you have inadvertently added Session[SessionName]=null. 2. I don't understand what you meant with null=null above, but I suggest you put a breakpoint Everywhere you .Clear() the session and also where you do Session[SessionName]=null. 3. Make sure there isn't another factor, like its using cookieless session and you have a link that doesn't go through asp.net's mechanism so it doesn't get the session ID in the link. And finally once you have checked all that if it still doesn't work, post an edit to your question with Plenty extra information,including code&settings.